# Почему range отрабатывает по разному

Tags: python

Кто может помочь и объяснить почему это  range из первого варианта отрабатывает не так, как во втором. Ведь логика практически одна и та же. Я исключаю 0 индекс и увеличиваю значение на 1, что бы стало 1000.

вариант 1

```
maxlen = 1001
res = 0
for i in range(1, maxlen):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        res += i
print(res)
```

вариант 2

```
result = sum([x for x in range(1000) if (x%3==0 or x%5==0)])
print(result)
```

результаты

```
234168
233168
```

Comment: Потому что в первом случае число i=1000 входит в range-диапазон и проверяется, а во втором не входит и не проверяется

Comment: `range(1, 1001)` != `range(1000)`

Answer (score 1):

Число `1000` подпадает под условие `if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0`, соответственно в сумму оно в первом случае попадает, а во втором нет, поскольку `range` выдаёт числа *исключая* верхнюю границу.

Тут `1000` попадает в цикл:

```
maxlen = 1001
for i in range(1, maxlen):
```

А тут не попадает:

```
x for x in range(1000)
```

**Количество** перебираемых элементов в обоих случаях одинаковое, а вот **сами элементы** - разные.